# Behavior of sub-solution of differential inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ obey the differential inequality
$$f'' - 2\alpha f' + 2\alpha f \leq 0$$
where $0 < \alpha < 2$ is some constant. If $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$, can I say that $f(x) < e^x - 1$ for some $x$?

Note that the solution to the corresponding differential equation oscillates since the characteristic equation has complex roots (call this solution $g$). Thus we can certainly say $g(x) < e^x -1$ for infinitely many $x$. My first thought was to try to control $f$ by $g$ a la Gronwall's inequality. However, I was recently shown that the analogue to Gronwall for degree two differential equations doesn't hold.

Any ideas would be welcome. Also, any good references for differential inequalities that might help me solve this problem are equally welcome.

Comment: If $\alpha< 1/2$ then $f''(0)<1$ and so $f(x)<e^x-1$ for $x>0$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Indeed. How about when $\alpha \in (.5,2)$

Comment: You don't have the maximum principle since $f''$ has the wrong sign, so it's not clear that this should be true. That is, without the maximum principle, subsolutions need not lie below supersolutions, etc.

Comment: I just need it to lie below at a point.

Comment: One thing you could try is to convert it to a system of first order ODEs (in matrix-vector form), and then try to control the norm of the solution with Gronwall.

Answer (score 0):

1. We shall solve the differential equation
   \begin{equation}
   y''-2\alpha y'+2\alpha y=0.
   \end{equation}
   The character equation can be obtained by substituting $y=\exp(\lambda x)$, i.e.
   \begin{equation}
   \lambda^2-2\alpha \lambda+2\alpha =0,
   \end{equation}
   which gives two roots,
   \begin{equation}
   \lambda_\pm=\alpha\pm i\sqrt{2 \alpha-\alpha ^2 }.
   \end{equation}
2. We then can rearrange the original inequality by using above two roots,
   \begin{equation}
   \left(f''-\lambda _- f'\right)-\lambda _+ \left(f'-\lambda _- f\right)\leq 0.
   \end{equation}
   Further, by defining a new variable by $F=f'-\lambda_- f$, we can rewrite the inequality
   \begin{equation}
   F'-\lambda _+ F\leq 0.
   \end{equation}
3. Then let us times a positive factor $\exp(-x\lambda_+ )$ on both sides of inequality, we obtain
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x\lambda_+ } F\right)\le 0,
   \end{equation}
   which gives a step solution
   \begin{equation}
   e^{-x\lambda_+ } F\le  F(0)=f'(0)-\lambda _- f(0)=1
   \end{equation}
   where we have used the initial conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$.
   Substituting $F=f'-\lambda_- f$ back, we arrive at
   \begin{equation}
   f'-\lambda_- f\le e^{x\lambda_+ }.
   \end{equation}
4. Again, we times a positive factor $\exp(-x\lambda_-)$ on both sides of above inequality, and get
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x\lambda_-}f\right)\le e^{x(\lambda_+-\lambda_-) }
   \end{equation}
   which can be solved by the similar method
   \begin{equation}
   f(x)\le\frac{e^{\lambda_+ x}-e^{\lambda_- x}}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-}=\frac{e^{\alpha  x} \sin \left(x\sqrt{(2-\alpha ) \alpha } \right)}{\sqrt{(2-\alpha) \alpha }},
   \end{equation}
   which is regarded as finial result.